# VAST Linear asset mismatch

Tags: ads, vast

I use Google Interactive Media Ads: Vast(V3) for iOS. I did download sample of iOS (Beta). And try to change content URL(kTestAppAdTagUrl_Instream1) to one of mine. And I got an error message

```
2014-03-31 14:34:30.531 SampleApp[1450:60b] Relayout
2014-03-31 14:34:30.565 SampleApp[1450:60b] AdsManager event (Loaded).
2014-03-31 14:34:31.364 SampleApp[1450:60b] AdsManager error with type: 2
code: 403
message: Linear assets were found in the VAST ad response, but none of them matched the video player's capabilities.
```

Here is my MediaFile Tag:

```
<MediaFiles>
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="400" width="640" height="480" type="video/x-mp4">
<![CDATA[
http://www.xxxx.mp4
]]>
</MediaFile>
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="400" width="640" height="480" type="video/x-flv">
<![CDATA[
http://www.xxxx.flv
]]>
</MediaFile>
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="400" width="640" height="480" type="video/webm">
<![CDATA[
http://www.xxxx.webm
]]>
</MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
```

And Here is original mediaFile Tag:

```
<MediaFiles>
<MediaFile id="GDFP" delivery="progressive" width="320" height="240" type="video/3gpp" bitrate="232">
<![CDATA[
http://redirector.gvt1.com/videoplayback/id/5c822b8b859554ed/itag/36/source/gfp_video_ads/ip/0.0.0.0/ipbits/0/expire/1396261757/sparams/ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source/signature/A9F9D4129DCC49C6DEA58E2883DD1BCC3B7C5581.15E62876AA0272EB01E0B8446A6705D29EDD8077/key/ck2/file/file.3gp
]]>
</MediaFile>
<MediaFile id="GDFP" delivery="progressive" width="470" height="360" type="video/mp4" bitrate="446">
<![CDATA[
http://redirector.gvt1.com/videoplayback/id/5c822b8b859554ed/itag/18/source/gfp_video_ads/ip/0.0.0.0/ipbits/0/expire/1396261757/sparams/ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source/signature/51703D4C36236250DDA8DC35D18361E09D90E971.4509891310D8FBE49A47C1249E126F851E0E8BB3/key/ck2/file/file.mp4
]]>
</MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
```

I don't know how can I fix this

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You have an incorrect type on your MP4 asset, video/x-mp4 won't work.

Change it to:

```
<MediaFile ... type="video/mp4"><![CDATA[http://www.xxxx.mp4]]></MediaFile>
```

**Valid:**
video/x-flv
video/mp4
video/webm
video/3gpp

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the invalid video file URL you passed? http://www.xxxx.mp4 ?